# NSDateFormatter return different results depending on iOS version

Tags: ios, ios5, date, ios6, nsdateformatter

I have a problem related to date formatter, it is returning null for the date "2012-10-21".

I created a sample project only with the code that I want to test, just to be sure that other things are not interfering in the results.

In iOS 5 it is executing as expected, but in iOS 6 the date formatter is returning null.

This is my code:

```
NSString *myStringDate = @"2012-10-21";

//------------------------//

NSLog(@"Test 1");

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *myDate = [formatter dateFromString:myStringDate];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", myDate);

//------------------------//

NSLog(@"Test 2");

NSDateFormatter *formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter2 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
[formatter2 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSDate *myDate2 = [formatter2 dateFromString:myStringDate];
NSLog(@"TimeZone: %@", [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]);
NSLog(@"Date: %@", myDate2);

//------------------------//

NSLog(@"Test 3");

NSDateFormatter *formatter3 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter3 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
[formatter3 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:-7200]];
NSDate *myDate3 = [formatter3 dateFromString:myStringDate];
NSLog(@"TimeZone: %@", [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:-7200]);
NSLog(@"Date: %@", myDate3);

//------------------------//
```

**iOS 5.1 simulator results:**

```
Test 1
Date: 2012-10-21 03:00:00 +0000

Test 2
TimeZone: America/Sao_Paulo (BRST) offset -7200 (Daylight)
Date: 2012-10-21 03:00:00 +0000

Test 3
TimeZone: GMT-0200 (GMT-02:00) offset -7200
Date: 2012-10-21 02:00:00 +0000
```

**iOS 6.0 simulator results:**

```
Test 1
Date: (null)

Test 2
TimeZone: America/Sao_Paulo (GMT-03:00) offset -7200 (Daylight)
Date: (null)

Test 3
TimeZone: GMT-0200 (GMT-02:00) offset -7200
Date: 2012-10-21 02:00:00 +0000
```

NSDateFormatter returns null in iOS 6 **only** when the date is `"2012-10-21"`. For all others dates of 2012 year, the result its correct on both iOS versions.

Anyone can explain why? Its a bug? My code is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Sau Paulo had a Daylight Saving change on the 20th/21st of October going forward an hour (http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=233). This doesn't seem like a coincidence. It's possible that the time calculated for Tests 1 and 2 fell between 12am-1am on the 21st October, which isn't possible. iOS 6 may be a bit more strict in this regard.

As far as I can tell, your code looks fine, it may be a bug within iOS (or it could be intended behavior, and iOS 5 was the issue, I can't tell!). The fact that other dates seemed to work suggests an OS issue, the documentation doesn't explain whether this should happen.

Comment: Hi WDUK. What you said makes a lot of sense. I tested for the years 2011, 2013 and 2014 and the bug will occur everyday where daylight saving time start at my timezone. Now I have to check what to do in this case to prevent the date formatter from returning nil. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It sounds like something that shouldn't happen, file a bug report with Apple regarding it (especially if iOS5 didn't return nil). http://bugreporter.apple.com/

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I am using to decrement the date:

- (IBAction)showPrevDate:(id)sender
  {
  NSString *dateForDecrement = _showDateLbl.text;

  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, yyyy (EEE)"];
  [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

  NSDate *dateObjectForDecrement = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateForDecrement];

  int subtractDays = 1;

  NSDate *dateAfterDecrement=[dateObjectForDecrement dateByAddingTimeInterval:-(24*60*60 * subtractDays)];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, yyyy (EEE)"];

  _showDateLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateAfterDecrement]];

}

Doesn't work with iOS6 but works with iOS5. Can you verify?